# PHP curl SFTP files list to array?

Tags: php, curl, sftp

I am using the code below to get all files from a folder via curl sftp.

```php
$ch = curl_init('sftp://' . $sftpServer . ':' . $sftpPort . $sftpRemoteDir . '/');
        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, '*******:*******');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DIRLISTONLY, '1L');
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

I have tried `explode()` and `preg_match()` but for some reason I can't parse the list of results:

```
641265471.txt_20220103_220501
641269117.txt_20220103_230501
..
```

How can I actually parse the data above to each new line being an array item ?

Comment: Does `$array = explode("\n", $response)` work?

Comment: unfortunately  no

Comment: `preg_split('~\R~', $response)` maybe ?

Comment: It seems curl_exec($ch); is automatically echo'ing the results and "$response" is = 1

Comment: @ClintC. Oh right, forgot the basics ! Glad to know it works the same for HTTP and SFTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely forgot to add

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

which is needed to capture the response.